# Spring Boot - Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im using the latest Spring Boot version, currently 2.2.2-RELEASE.

I have this endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> post(@RequestParam(required = false) MultiValueMap<?, ?> paramMap) throws Exception {
    // CODE
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If I call it (from postman) setting the body as a x-www-form.urlencoded all is fine and I receive my 200 OK status code.

But if I modify the above endpoint (adding another parameter) as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> post(@RequestParam(required = false) MultiValueMap<?, ?> paramMap, RequestEntity<?> req) throws Exception {
    // CODE
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I receive this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1576961587242,
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/test"
}
```

Something is missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I understand, the default argument resolvers can resolve `MultiValueMap` for the given `content-type`. But for `RequestEntity`, none of the default resolvers support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. So to support it, you need to add your own custom resolver. You can debug method `readWithMessageConverters` in `AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver` class to get clear idea

Comment: If you really need to support this `content-type` for `RequestEntity`, here is a resource to create custom message converter: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/custom-http-message-converter.html

Comment: Thank you for your support! Your's a valid solution but I need more control cause I want to capture all mediatypes so it's a little bit difficult implementing it for every types. Anyway I have an initial solution that I proposed as an answer. Let me know what do you think, maybe I'm wrong with something! Thank you again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Sunil Dabburi suggests debugging the `readWithMessageConverters` method in the `AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver` sheds light on this issue, which turns out to be pretty simple once understood. Spring has about 15 default message converters, which are responsible for converting the content of an incoming request to a `RequestEntity` or `HttpEntity`. If the request has body, the converter reads it and converts it to the object type it is responsible for. Depending on the incoming request's Media Type, each converter decides whether it can read the request. In the case of the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Media Type none of the default Spring converters can process such a request. Therefore, the above mentioned error occurs.

Adding a custom converter for the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Media Type to the list of Spring's http message converters would solve the issue. In the example below the custom converter is responsible only for reading requests and only for requests with the desired Media Type.

** These reads help understanding the media type itself and how does spring work with it, thus how should the custom converter convert the incoming request:

- [About the media type](https://dev.to/sidthesloth92/understanding-html-form-encoding-url-encoded-and-multipart-forms-3lpa)
- [Default Spring handling and why does it work with MultiValueMap as only parameter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-url-encoded-form-data)
- [The needed request body object type (MultiValueMap<String, String>) for Spring to create RequestEntity/HttpEntity for this media type](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template#exchange_post-1)

Here is an example of such custom http message converter:

```
@Component
public class FormUrlencodedHttpMessageConverter extends 
AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter<MultiValueMap<String, String>> {

private static final MediaType CONVERTER_MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED;

public FormUrlencodedHttpMessageConverter() {
    super(CONVERTER_MEDIA_TYPE);
}

@Override
public MultiValueMap<String, String> read(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {

    String urlEncodedData = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputMessage.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).readLine();

    String[] keyValuePairs = urlEncodedData.split("&");
    MultiValueMap<String, String> keyValuePairsMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

    for (String keyValuePair : keyValuePairs) {
        String[] pairElements = keyValuePair.split("=");
        String key = pairElements[0];
        String value = pairElements[1];
        keyValuePairsMap.add(key, value);
    }

    return keyValuePairsMap;
}

@Override
protected boolean canRead(@Nullable MediaType mediaType) {

    return CONVERTER_MEDIA_TYPE.includes(mediaType);
}

@Override
protected boolean canWrite(@Nullable MediaType mediaType) {

    return CONVERTER_MEDIA_TYPE.includes(mediaType);
}

@Override
protected void writeInternal(MultiValueMap<String, String> t, Type type, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    throw new RuntimeException("Method 'writeInternal' in " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is not implemented");
}

@Override
protected MultiValueMap<String, String> readInternal(Class<? extends MultiValueMap<String, String>> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    throw new RuntimeException("Method 'readInternal' in " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is not implemented");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and for you time

Comment: Some comments : `canWrite` can return true, but calling `writeInternal` always fails. On the read side, there is absolutely no encoding-related logic, which surely is bound to fail. You're assuming UTF-8 - probably safe these days, but your mileage may vary. But more importantly, you're not URL decoding ("percent decoding") anything. This may fail often in various international settings. I advide you implement your parsing more along the lines of Spring's FormHttpMessageConverter, which provides all this logic.

Comment: @GPI the purpose for the `canWrite` to be able to return true and for the `writeInternal` to fail is to have the option to be notified if the `writeInternal` method in this converter is reached (in case this is the use case). I agree that if this is not the use case, the `canWrite` can always return false if the converter will be used for reading only. 

About the parsing, thank you for the tips and advice! It is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of search I found a lot of material but I didn't like the proposed solutions.
So I decided to experiment different approaches.
At the moment I developed this code, autowiring the `HttpServletRequest` I'm able to access to all desired values like headers, body, params. So I start intercepting it and then I create my customized `HttpEntity`.
Here's the code if someone is facing the same problem and please feel free to suggests modifications and improvements.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/**", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> post(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws Exception {
    String url = servletRequest.getRequestURI().replaceFirst("/", "");

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = (Collections
            .list(servletRequest.getHeaderNames())
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Function.identity(),
                    h -> Collections.list(servletRequest.getHeaders(h)),
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue,
                    HttpHeaders::new
            ))
    );

    HttpEntity<?> request;

    String body = servletRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    if (!body.isEmpty()) {
        request = new HttpEntity<>(body, httpHeaders);
    } else {
        Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap<>();
        Stream.of(servletRequest.getParameterMap()).forEach(stringMap -> stringMap.forEach((k, v) ->
                Stream.of(v).forEach(value -> payload.put(k, value))
        ));
        request = new HttpEntity<>(payload, httpHeaders);
    }

    return getSuccessResponse(proxyService.doProxyTest(request, url, new HttpPost(url)));
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, using `RequestEntity` which is an extension of `HttpEntity` can save you some code instead of `HttpServletRequest`. For example `getHeaders()` gives you `HttpHeaders` so you don’t need to iterate through individual headers and construct it. But it may cause same 415 error for form media type I believe.

Comment: Yes always 415. Only intercepting the request as HttpServletRequest seems to work!