# x-www-form-urlencoded Array inconsistently populated in Spring REST call

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, curl, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am attempting to send a PUT request to a Rest API using x-www-form-urlencoded content. My aim is to send a list of strings in the request similar to [this article](https://dev.to/bcanseco/request-body-encoding-json-x-www-form-urlencoded-ad9). I have the following REST controller defined in a Spring Boot application to allow for this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/api", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RestApiController {

    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private ReturnType putRestApiTypeJson(
        @PathVariable("id") String id,
        @ModelAttribute PutDataRequest request) {
    
        System.out.println();
        return null;
        
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    private ReturnType putRestApiTypeUrlEncoded(
        @PathVariable("id") String id,
        @ModelAttribute PutDataRequest request) {
    
        System.out.println();
        return null;
        
    }
}
```

which leverages `PutDataRequest` defined by:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PutDataRequest {

    Set<String> characters = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> movies = new HashMap<>();

}
```

I try hitting the rest api controller via curl to perform testing. The Application JSON PUT request receives characters and movies no problem, however the form-urlencoded endpoint does so inconsistently:

// No data populated in `PutDataRequest` at debug time:
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:some-port/rest/api' -d 'characters=Some%20Name%26movies=Some%20Title' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

// Data populated in `PutDataRequest` at debug time:
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:some-port/rest/api?characters=Some%20Name%26movies=Some%20Title' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Can anyone give an insight on why providing the key-value pairs via -d prevents the data from being forwarded to the form-urlencoded PUT endpoint? For context, I run this coded using spring version 5.2.3.RELEASE and spring boot version 2.2.4.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also found another way to get around this error. Turns out PUT and DELETE requests aren't enabled by default, and you need to add an implementation for the [formContentFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.html#formContentFilter().) method in your `Application.java` (or wherever you call `SpringApplication.run(...)` )

Once I added the following to Application.java, I ran again and it worked like magic:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="spring.mvc.formcontent.filter", name="enabled", matchIfMissing=true)
public OrderedFormContentFilter formContentFilter() {
    return new OrderedFormContentFilter();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to sidestep Spring in this situation. Instead of relying on Spring to figure out how to marshal the data I wanted, I added a `HttpServletRequest` to the form-urlencoded method signature and pulled the data out of the request:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
private ReturnType putRestApiTypeUrlEncoded(
    @PathVariable("id") String id,
    @ModelAttribute PutDataRequest data,
    HttpServletRequest request) {

String body = request.getRequest().lines()
    .map(line -> URLDecoder.decode(line, Charset.defaultCharset()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

// manipulate body content to extract desired data
    
}
```

I was inspired to do the above by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59441195/3753021).